# Load xml file with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to load a XML File with an absolute path. I have tried doing this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Users\Accueil\Desktop\TestEDI\ARTest.xml");
```

But I get the error:

> the character '<', hexadecimal value 0x3c, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: Can you show your file content? It looks like your xml is not valid.

Comment: The name the error message is referring to is probably not the name of the file but a malformed element name in the XML file

Comment: Error probably comes from the file content but because i can't change the content, i have decided to not use XmlDocument to read and parse my xml.

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error if you have a use of `<` other than as the open tag of an xml element.

1. For example, `<my<Element>` could give you this error, because the parser finds the second `<` while it is expecting either part of the tag name for `myElement` or the closing tag `>`.
2. Another example would be that you wanted to use `<` in the body of some xml text:

   `<inequality>`Here is an example of an inequality: x < 5`</inequality>`

The way to avoid this is to make sure that all non opening tag uses of '<' are encoded as [proper XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML), in this case, that would be `&lt;`

Answer (score 1):

As Andy has said it looks as though you are using restricted characters in your xml file...

[Taken from here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)...

This gives an error message:

```
<message>if salary < 1000 then</message>
```

This is fine:

```
<message>if salary &lt; 1000 then</message>
```

There are 5 pre-defined entity references in XML:

```
&lt;    <   less than
&gt;    >   greater than
&amp;   &   ampersand 
&apos;  '   apostrophe
&quot;  "   quotation mark
```

Note: Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML. The greater than character is legal, but it is a good habit to replace it.

So replace those illegal characters or consider using [CData](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlReader xmlFile; 
FileStream fs = new FileStream("/*YOUR XML FILE PATH*/.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); // Creates a FileStream that will open a specific .xml file you want, read it and then write its data into your program
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(fs, new XmlReaderSettings()); // Enables your program to use this newly "created" .xml file

DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile); // Uses your .xml file as a DataSet, which can then be used as a data source for something you need (e.g.: a DataGridView)
```

Comment: PS.: when hardcoding a file path, you should always use \\ instead of \, so your path would be like "C:\\Users\\Accueil\\Desktop\\TestEDI\\ARTest.xml"

Comment: In this particular case OP has escaped slashes in sting by using `@` prefix - so there is no need to use double slashes.